# springboot map-underscore-to-camel-case invalid

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

My spring version is 1.5.2, spring-mybatis-start version is 1.3.2,
I set `mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true` in properties.
But the MAP I returned was not converted to **Camel** named

Here is my configuration

`mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true`

Comment: Why do you expect this setting to affect maps? Mybatis docs says it  `Enables automatic mapping from classic database column names A_COLUMN to camel case classic Java property names aColumn`.

Comment: The amount .... Because sometimes I even query the table, there will be a lot of columns returned, this time is not suitable for the definition of javabean, that would look very embarrassing, so I want to return a map, and then convert the map inside the key to Camel named

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been sovled,the plan is as follows

```
public class CustomWrapper extends MapWrapper{

public CustomWrapper(MetaObject metaObject, Map<String, Object> map) {
    super(metaObject, map);
}

// useCamelCaseMapping is map-underscore-to-camel-case field
@Override
public String findProperty(String name, boolean useCamelCaseMapping) {
    if(useCamelCaseMapping){
        return CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL,name);
    }
    return name;
}
}
```

---

```
public class MapWrapperFactory implements ObjectWrapperFactory {

@Override
public boolean hasWrapperFor(Object object) {
    return object != null && object instanceof Map;
}

@Override
public ObjectWrapper getWrapperFor(MetaObject metaObject, Object object) {
    return new CustomWrapper(metaObject,(Map)object);
}
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class MybatisConfig {

@Bean
public ConfigurationCustomizer mybatisConfigurationCustomizer(){
    return new ConfigurationCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration) {
            configuration.setObjectWrapperFactory(new MapWrapperFactory());
        }
    };
}
}
```